# Escaping single quote

Tags: bash, quoting, cygwin

I had to wipe my drive and reinstall windows, which also required reinstalling cygwin.

In my new install,

```
ls -l "*\'*"
```

returns

```
ls: cannot access '*\'\''*': No such file or directory
```

For years up until this point, `ls -l *\'*` would present me a list of directories and files where users had included a single quote in file or directory names.

Any tips on what I may be missing about this situation?

For example, apparently coreutils had some changes that caused files with spaces in the name to be listed as 'This File contains spaces' and a switch/variable had to be used to turn it off.

I'm wondering if some similar change in standard use was implemented regarding the single quote.

Comment: What did you expect to happen/what used to happen when you did that?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot quote `*` if you expect it to act as a wildcard.  Both single and double quotes escape it.

Double quotes also escape single quotes so your whole string `*\'*` is going to be taken literally:

```
$ echo "*\'*"
*\'*
```

You want to write your string without the double quotes as you have written later in your question:

```
ls -l *\'*
```

---

Another way to do this that may be better suited for you is with the `find` command.  (which does not follow the same quoting rules as above so sorry for the confusion).  With find you can search a directory structure recursively much easier for any file containing a single quote with the below command:

```
find . -name "*'*"
```

In this example `.` stands for the directory you are currently in but you can replace that with a path to any directory you would like to search.

Comment: Thanks Jesse_b.
I was pretty sure when I used no quotes, the ls command was failing. Apparently it does work, so my question was somewhat irrelevant in the long run. I thought maybe something had changed in the code.